# Setting word font size between lyrics in MusixTeX for Flam Accent Drum Rudiment

Tags: musixtex, musixper

It is needed to configure the word font size in musixlyr package, the code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{R}{L R L R R L R L}% added for hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-4mm}
      \largemusicsize
      \setlines{1}{0}
      \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule
      \startextract
      \A\assignlyrics1{R}% added to place handindication
      \Notes\charnote f{\Huge{\textcircled{\Large 21}}}\sk\en%$\quad$ lifted the number, \sk is the music way to skip one noteskip
      \notes\stdstemfalse\smallnotesize\islurd0a\grcu a\en
      \NOtes \tslur0a\ibu0a0\usf g\qb0{aa}\tbu0\qb0a \en
      \notes\stdstemfalse\smallnotesize\islurd0a\grcu a\en
      \NOtes \tslur0a\ibu0a0\usf g\qb0{aa}\tbu0\qb0a \en
      \zendextract
\end{music} 

\end{document}
```

the output is as follow:
[image: current output]

The expected output has to be as follow (small font size for flam):

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two changes suggested: simpler way to choose a smaller lettertype in music, and using tinynotesize for grace notes.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


%\newcommand{\flam}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<  
%   \bgroup\sffamily \bfseries\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont #1\egroup
%} not necessary in music, see added font B


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{music}
        \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
        \font\B=phvb8t at 6pt% second fontsize, 8pt possible, too
        \setlyrics{R}{\B{L} R L R \B{R} L R L}% added for hand indication changed again !!!
        \setsongraise1{-4mm}
        \largemusicsize
        \setlines{1}{0}
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
        \startextract
        \A\assignlyrics1{R}% added to place handindication
        \Notes\charnote f{\Huge{\textcircled{\Large 21}}}\sk\en%$\quad$ lifted the number, \sk is the music way to skip one noteskip
        \notes\stdstemfalse\tinynotesize\islurd0a\grcu a\en% with tinynotesize the difference is greater, like in your intended output, compare with second gracenote
        \NOtes \tslur0a\ibu0a0\usf g\qb0{aa}\tbu0\qb0a \en
        \notes\stdstemfalse\smallnotesize\islurd0a\grcu a\en
        \NOtes \tslur0a\ibu0a0\usf g\qb0{aa}\tbu0\qb0a \en
        \zendextract
    \end{music} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image: tinynotesize, smaller lettertype]

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\newcommand{\flam}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<  
    \bgroup\sffamily \bfseries\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont #1\egroup
}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{music}
        \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
        \setlyrics{R}{\flam{L} R L R \flam{R} L R L}% added for hand indication changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \setsongraise1{-4mm}
        \largemusicsize
        \setlines{1}{0}
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
        \startextract
        \A\assignlyrics1{R}% added to place handindication
        \Notes\charnote f{\Huge{\textcircled{\Large 21}}}\sk\en%$\quad$ lifted the number, \sk is the music way to skip one noteskip
        \notes\stdstemfalse\smallnotesize\islurd0a\grcu a\en
        \NOtes \tslur0a\ibu0a0\usf g\qb0{aa}\tbu0\qb0a \en
        \notes\stdstemfalse\smallnotesize\islurd0a\grcu a\en
        \NOtes \tslur0a\ibu0a0\usf g\qb0{aa}\tbu0\qb0a \en
        \zendextract
    \end{music} 
    
\end{document}
```